# How to set up the Django tag for django-google-analytics-app?

Tags: html, django, google-analytics, django-templates, google-analytics-api

**SUMMARY**

I am installing ***django-google-analytics-app*** following the instructions in this link https://pypi.org/project/django-google-analytics-app/ .

For the pages I am interested in doing the tracking I am including analytics.html in their templates in the body section as essentially shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}

<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {% include "analytics.html" %}
  </body>
</html>
```

where analytics.html only has the lines instructed in the link:

```
{% load google_analytics_tags %}
<div style="display:none">
    <img src="{% google_analytics %}" width="0" height="0" />
</div>
```

**THE PROBLEM**

This is disturbing the styling of my pages.

**THE QUESTION**

How am I meant to include the tracking in the templates/pages I want to do so?

Comment: Change your styling to accommodate it then? Or include the app in the other way, using middleware & celery?

Comment: How would I decide which templates to track? Or would it track all of them by default and I only specify the ones I don't want tracking with ```GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_IGNORE_PATH = ['/health/', ]``` ?